# Updating a variable

Tags: macros

I define a variable using `\def\x{0}`. How can I update this variable by adding 1?

`\def\x{\x+1}` doesnt work (it just gets stuck in an infinite loop)

Or can I define variables in some other way that can do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: If you only want to manipulate integers, you can use `\newcounter{x} \addtocounter{x}{1}`. You can access the value via `\value{x}`; in particular, `\the\value{xx}` print the value of counter x.

Comment: @Jubobs You have a wrong `\the\value{xx}` that should be `\the\value{x}` (or the simpler `\arabic{x}`).

Comment: Oops. You're right.

Comment: @egreg: Or another simpler one (compared to `\arabic{x}`): `\thex`.

Comment: @Karl'sstudents `\thex` might have been redefined.

Answer (score 8):

It's better to manage integer variables with TeX's registers. You can say

```
\newcount\x
```

and then use it in all contexts a number is required. Advancing a counter is done by

```
\advance\x by 1
```

or any other integer. In order to print the value of this counter you have to say `\number\x`.

However, it depends on what you want to do with those "variables". A different approach might be

```
\def\newvariable#1{\gdef#1{0}}
\def\addtovariable#1#2{\xdef#1{\number\numexpr#1+#2\relax}}
\def\incrvariable#1{\addtovariable#1{1}}
```

so that

```
\newvariable\x
```

will define `\x` to expand to 0; with

```
\incrvariable\x
```

it would expand to 1; with a following

```
\addtovariable\x{41}
```

it would expand to 42. Not that I recommend such a way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Without PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
% #1: (optional) the number of digits after decimal point, the default is zero to make an integer
% #2: (mandatory) the name of variable to create
% #3: (mandatory) mathematics expression in infix form
\newcommand\const[3][0]{%
    \edef\temporary{round(#3}%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\temporary:#1)}%
}

\const{x}{10}
\const{y}{x^2}

\begin{document}
\x% print 10

\const{x}{x+20}% add 20 to x

\x% print 30

\y% print 100, not 900!
\end{document}
```

### *Application (finding the fixed point of cos(x))*

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
% #1: (optional) the number of digits after decimal point, the default is zero to make an integer
% #2: (mandatory) the name of variable to create
% #3: (mandatory) mathematics expression in infix form
\newcommand\const[3][0]{%
    \edef\temporary{round(#3}%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\temporary:#1)}\ignorespaces
}

\def\f(#1){cos(#1)}

\const[5]{x}{0}

\begin{document}
\newcount\i
\i=1
\loop
    \unless\ifnum\i>35
        \advance \i by 1
        \const[5]{x}{\f(x)}
        \x
        \par
\repeat
\end{document}
```